# add jquery tab from outside page

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, service

I have an application that uses jquery tabs to open up different asp.net applications from its "menu" tab.  The content of the tabs is an iframe with the application.  What I need is for one of the application tabs that is inside an iframe to open a page in a new tab.  I am running the apps in iis 7 with asp.net.  how can I send a signal to the "tabs" application to open a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

`window.parent` will allow you to access the outer app.

Answer (score 0):

as @Anthony suggested you can use `window.parent` and `window.parent.document` to access objects on the parent window containing `iframe`, but better way will be to write a function on parent window to open new window and then call that from `iframe` code because it is more foolproof.

```
//in parent window
window.openNewWindow = function(/*ANY PARAMS*/){
                            //open window here
                       };

//in iframe

parent.window.openNewWindow(/*PARAMAS (IF ANY)*/);
```